# Server Error 500 when deploying Go backend with Gorm, using CloudSQL and Google App Engine

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, go-gorm

I'm trying to deploy a Go backend on Google App Engine, connecting to CloudSQL. Deploy magic is working, but when I try to call the API, I get a 500 status:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

When running `gcloud app logs tail -s default`, I have:

```
2020/06/07 21:39:26 server.go:52: dial unix /cloudsql/: connect: is a directory
```

```
    var dbURI string
    dbURI = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@unix(/cloudsql/%s)/%s", dbUser, dbPwd, dbHost, dbName)

    // Open database connection
    db, err := gorm.Open(
        "mysql",
        dbURI,
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) <-- line 52
    }
```

My app.yaml is setup correctly (I think..):

```
env_variables:
  CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME: 'XXXXX:europe-west1:XXXXXX'
  DB_USER: 'root'
  DB_PASS: 'XXXXX'
  DB_NAME: 'XXXXX'
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have code that uses the environment variable `CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME`?

Answer (score 0):

I was indeed not using the right ENV variable.. Thank you for pointing that out @Muffin Top